# Packet serialization in C++

Tags: c++, oop, serialization, packet

I have a project that does packet serialization of several different types(`Packet1`, `Packet2`...). They all extend a `PacketHeader` class and does its own serialization

This approach seems very messy and error-prone, especially as the number of fields grows.

Is there a cleaner and more OOP & C++ way for serialization(without 3rd-party library)?

```
class PacketHeader {
    uint8_t type;
    uint32_t id;
    uint32_t seqNum;

    virtual void serialize(uint8_t *buf, size_t size) {
        int offset = 0;
        PacketHeader n;
        n.type = type;
        n.id = htonl(id);
        n.seqNum = htonl(seqNum);
        memcpy(buf + offset, &(n.type), sizeof(n.type));
        offset += sizeof(n.type);
        memcpy(buf + offset, &(n.id), sizeof(n.id));
        offset += sizeof(n.id);
        memcpy(buf + offset, &n.seqNum, sizeof(n.seqNum));
        offset += sizeof(n.seqNum);
    }
}

class Packet1 : public PacketHeader {
    uint32_t payload;

    virtual void serialize(uint8_t *buf, size_t size) {
        int offset = PacketHeader::size();
        PacketHeader::serialize(buf, size);
        memcpy(buf + offset, &n.payload, sizeof(n.payload));
        offset += sizeof(n.payload);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Doing serialization natively on structures and classes with data members requires you to feed the offset, size, and type information for each member to the serializer.  That's the source of the "messy" aspect and you can't avoid it no matter how elegant your design.

There are some helper libraries that can provide some structure to that but they're generally just syntax candy and are still pretty hard to maintain as the number of message types grows.

Instead I would recommend looking at systems that provide dictionaries -- key/value data objects -- rather than using native C++ structure/class data members.  Some use standard serialization formats such as JSON.  JSONCPP is a very well regarded package that does this:  http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/

Mostly they provide the advantage that the software system will scale better as it grows and won't become an exponential maintenance headache.

If binary serialization is desired, take a look at BSON, MessagePack, Google Protocol Buffers, and Apache Thrift.  They all offer libraries or bindings for C++.